# How to use System.Guid.Parse in framework 3.5

Tags: .net, frameworks, guid, uniqueidentifier

I was building my BLL with the .Net Framework 4.0 but then I noticed I needed it for a WebServices app, so I changed the .Net version to 3.5. Now I have this line of code giving me an error:

`tmp.GlobalIdentifier = Guid.Parse(Convert.ToString(row["GlobalIdentifier"]));`

The error is

> 'System.Guid' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

which is a very clear error. Do you have any equivalent "Parse" method in any other class? What would be the best way to parse a SQL Server UniqueIdentifier into a System.Guid object using .Net framework 3.5?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try `tmp.GlobalIdentifier = new Guid(Convert.ToString(row["GlobalIdentifier"]))`

[Linking MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. I saw a bunch of Regex solutions for this problem, but I wanted something more like this (let .net do the work for me). Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 5):

```
Guid myGuid = new Guid("B80D56EC-5899-459d-83B4-1AE0BB8418E4");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the .NET type you are using to store the SQL Server UniqueIdentifier?

If it's the [SqlGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid.aspx) struct, you can just use the provided [explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1cxwz67.aspx):

```
tmp.GlobalIdentifier = (Guid)(SqlGuid)row["GlobalIdentifier"];
```

If you are using a string that `Guid` can accept, then you can just use the constructor overload of `Guid` that accepts a string, as others have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Kindly Ani. In fact I myself don't store data on this table, but just retrieve it so I ignore how it is being done. I will, however use this for sure if the opportunity comes. Thanks for the help.